# In what situation will a conformal transformation leave the vacuum invariant

Tags: conformal-field-theory, vacuum

Recently I am reading Francesco's CFT. In section 5.4.2, it considers a generic CFT living on the entire complex plane and maps this theory on a cylinder of circumference L by the transformation:
$$
z\rightarrow \omega=\frac{L}{2\pi}\ln z
$$
The corresponding energy-momentum tensor can be evaluated using (5.124):
$$
T_{cyl.}(\omega)=\left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)^2\left\{T_{pl.}z^2-\frac{c}{24}\right\} 
$$
Then it assumes that the vacuum energy density $<T_{pl.}>$ vanishes on the plane (Why can we assume that?) and the above equation yields a nonzero vacuum energy density on the cylinder
$$
<T_{cyl.}(\omega)>=-\frac{c\pi^2}{6L^2}
$$

My question is: Does the conformal transformation above change the vacuum state?

If it does, the vacuum of the plane is different from that of the cylinder and the statement above will be incorrect because $<T_{pl.}>$ may not vanish in the new vacuum. I know that in relativity the accelerating frame's vacuum is not the same to that of a inertial frame.

So in what situation is the vacuum invariant under conformal transformation? How do the creation and annihilation operators change under conformal transformations? On page 157, at the beginning of 6.2.2 it is said that the vacuum state must be invariant under global conformal transformations, but why? How about local conformal transformations?

Thank you!